# Editing array also changes another array

Tags: c#, arrays, console

So I'm making a little game in the windows console (just for fun and to test theories) but I am having an issue with the `DrawGame()` method.

I am creating a new string array (`string[] _CompleteMap`) with its values being assigned from  `CurrentMap.MapData` (which is also a string array):

`string[] _CompleteMap = CurrentMap.MapData;`

I am using the `CurrentMap.MapData` as a blank map, then changing characters within the strings to represent the player and mobs.
But when I make a change to `_CompleteMap` it also seems to be changing the values in `CurrentMap.MapData`...

I have no idea why this is happening and it is leaving a trail of where the user walked.

Any support would be helpful and I can post the code if required.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using ConsoleAdventure.Engine.BaseClasses;
using Database = ConsoleAdventure.Engine.Database;

namespace ConsoleAdventure
{
    class Program
    {
        private static bool whileGameScene = true;
        private static Engine.BaseClasses.MapBase CurrentMap;

        static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load and populate the databases.
            Database.ItemDB.LoadItemDB();
            Database.MapDB.LoadMapDB();

            // Set demo map
            CurrentMap = Database.MapDB.Maps[0];

            // Hide cursor
            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            // Start a new thread to capture the user inputs
            new Thread(() =>
                        {
                            while (true)
                            {
                                Thread.CurrentThread.IsBackground = true;

                                ConsoleKeyInfo cki = Console.ReadKey();

                                if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.A && Player.Data.Location.X > 0)
                                    Player.Data.Location.X--;
                                else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D)
                                    Player.Data.Location.X++;
                                else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.W && Player.Data.Location.Y > 0)
                                    Player.Data.Location.Y--;
                                else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.S)
                                    Player.Data.Location.Y++;

                                CheckWarpPoints();
                            }        
                        }).Start();

            // Draw the game
            while (whileGameScene)
            {
                DrawGame();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check if player has stood on a warp zone
        /// </summary>
        private static void CheckWarpPoints()
        {
            foreach (MapBase.WarpPoint warp in Database.MapDB.Maps[Player.Data.CurrentMap].WarpPoints)
            {
                if (Player.Data.Location.X == warp.From.X && Player.Data.Location.Y == warp.From.Y)
                {
                    Player.Data.CurrentMap = warp.ToMapIndex;
                    Player.Data.Location = warp.To;
                }
            }
        }

        public static void DrawGame()
        {
            string[] _CompleteMap = CurrentMap.MapData;

            StringBuilder _sbRow = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var _object in CurrentMap.MapObjects)
            {
                _sbRow = new StringBuilder(_CompleteMap[_object.CurrentLocation.Y]);
                _sbRow[_object.CurrentLocation.X] = _object.Icon;
                _CompleteMap[_object.CurrentLocation.Y] = _sbRow.ToString();
            }

            _sbRow = new StringBuilder(_CompleteMap[Player.Data.Location.Y]);
            _sbRow[Player.Data.Location.X] = 'X';
            _CompleteMap[Player.Data.Location.Y] = _sbRow.ToString();

            for (int i = 0; i < _CompleteMap.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, i);
                Console.WriteLine(_CompleteMap[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since arrays are reference types, when you do this:

```
string[] _CompleteMap = CurrentMap.MapData;
```

You're essentially creating a new variable that points to the same memory location as `CurrentMap.MapData`, and any changes you make to that location through `_CompleteMap` will also show up when you refer to the location via `CurrentMap.MapData`.

Instead you can create a new array based on the contents of the existing array:

```
string[] _CompleteMap = CurrentMap.MapData.ToArray();
```

Now it's pointing to a different location, so modifications to the array in this location will not affect the array in the original location.

---

One thing to note, however, is that if `MapData` were an array of a reference type and you used `ToArray()` to make a copy of it, then even though you now have a new array containing the same data, if you manipulate one of the objects in the copy of the array, the change to that object will appear in the original array as well.

This is because we did a *shallow* copy. If we didn't want this behavior, then we'd need to do a *deep* copy instead, where we also create new (cloned) instances of every object in the array as well. Something for you to research!!

For example:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Original array has a person named John
        Person[] people = new [] { new Person { Name = "John" } };

        // Create a shallow copy of the array
        Person[] peopleCopy = people.ToArray();

        // Change John's name in the copy
        peopleCopy[0].Name = "James";

        // At this point, people[0].Name is also "James", since it's the same person!

        // However changes to the array itself are discreet
        peopleCopy[0] = new Person { Name = "Mary" };

        // At this point, people[0].Name is still "James", since we did
        // not modify the existing object, but instead created a new one
    }
}
```